# ERC-20 token with identitfication

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I would like to create a generic ERC-20 token with identification. The token would only be transferred to previously identified addresses. The way identification is implemented should be as decoupled as possible from the token itself.

We also want to reuse this token in different scenarios (with different business rules). Is there any standard or reference to this goal?

Comment: `reuse this token in different scenarios (with different business rules)` - Do you actually expect to get a reference to that? It's like saying "I want to do stuff, can you give me a reference to this goal?"!

Comment: I think I described what stuff means in this case. Glad if you can contribute

Comment: With regards to `The token would only be transferred to previously identified addresses` - this is generally referred to as KYC (Know Your Customer), so you can look it up. With regards to `reuse this token in different scenarios` - like I said, this is a general statement, which I doubt that anyone can help you with (when you ask for something, you need to know what it is, and you to know how to explain to others what it is).

Comment: The closes thing I know are security tokens. Polymath has an implementation https://github.com/PolymathNetwork/polymath-core. There are other proposals for the same type of token [EIP 1450](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1450),  and [EIP 1462](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1462).